# .so file generation android GStreamer v1.16.1

Tags: android, video-streaming, shared-libraries, gstreamer

This is a multi-part question. That I have regarding the .so file generation of GStreamer.

I need to upgrade from 1.14.4 to 1.16.1 version. I followed [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/for-android-development.html?gi-language=c#building-the-tutorials) to generate the required .so files.

In the project, [gst-launch-remote](https://github.com/sdroege/gst-launch-remote/blob/master/gst-launch-remote/gst-launch-remote.c) is being used. If I try and build GStreamer 1.16.1 with NDK 18. I get

`error: undefined reference to 'gst_net_client_clock_new' clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1`

I double-checked and the variable being referenced is present in the source code and the required header files are also included.

**Question -- How do I resolve this build issue?**

For the time being, I commented out the line which caused the build failure with which I can generate the .so files.

The .so files being generated are huge ~ 150 MBs. Which has massively increased the size of the .APK file. The current one being used in the project is around 40-50 MBs.

**Question -- Is there any way to reduce the size of the .so files?**

When I dug deeper. I found two .so files being generated inside the path

```
.../android-launch/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86_64
```

One was the GStreamer and another was the 'C' file that I was using as JNI. But in my output folder I just the GStreamer .so.

**Question -- Is the 'C' .so file acts as an interface to the GStreamer .so file? Does anyone know why the other 'C' .so is used for?**

**Question -- Is there a way I can generate multiple .so files which can as an interface to GStreamer .so file? If yes, then how?**

Comment: I think it would be useful if you share your .mk file here. I'm not sure but you might need to ad `$(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET)` to your `GSTREAMER_PLUGINS` variable

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have resolved the build issue. If you know how to reduce the size of the .so files, I would like to know. I think by removing plugins from the plugins.mk helps but the difference is almost insignificant.

Comment: Did u managed to reduce the size? I faced the same.

Comment: Sorry, I was away. I am unable to fix this as of now. I'll update once I start working on this again.

Comment: Can you verify that the .so files were stripped? Cause 150MB is definitely too big

Comment: Yes, I did verify.